# Multiple underscores randomly in a string

Tags: javascript, html

I want random multiple underscores every time I refresh the page in a string...

```
<html>
  <body>
   <p id="demo"></p>
   <p id="temo"></p>
   <p id="jemo"></p>
   <p id="remo"></p>
   <script>
     var i;
     var x="Sachin Tendulkar";//String in which i want underscores
     var res=x.split("");
     for(i=1;i<=7;i++)//here in this for loop i generated random numbers and accessing the elements at that indexes and try to put underscores there.
     {
       var j = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=Math.floor(Math.random()*         ((x.length-1)/2));
       var t = res[j];
       var f = document.getElementById("jemo").innerHTML=x.replace(res[j],"_");
       var l = document.getElementById("jemo").innerHTML=f.replace(res[j],"_");

     }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: And I want you to read about [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: By using `Math.floor(Math.random()*         ((x.length-1)/2)`, are you trying to replace characters at only first word of `x`?

Comment: Why would you delete _or doubly post_ all of your code? This only drastically reduces the quality of your question.

Comment: I want to replace random characters.

Comment: @holly do you mean something like that `x.replace(/\S/g, char => Math.random() < .5? "_": char)`?

Comment: Only characters in first word or both words?

Comment: @guest271314, I guess he wants to replace a total of 7 chars with an underscore. Not restraining the algo to the first 7 characters.

Comment: @holly Expected result is unclear

Comment: expected result is-

Comment: for example-sac_h_n t_ndu_k_r,_achin _end_lk_r,s_c_in t_n_ul_a_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute using `.slice()`, `.concat()` for `.replace()`.

```js
var x = "Sachin Tendulkar";
for (var i = 1, y = x; i < 7; i++) {
  // alternatively `Math.floor(Math.random() * x.length)`
  var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((x.length - 1) / 2));
  y = y.slice(0, n).concat("_", y.slice(n + 1))
}

console.log(y);
```